# Ways to find three curves from palm image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am asked to extract three curves from palm images. 
[image]
    original image

[image]
    expected result.
The curves has lower intensity than neighboring pixels. So I try to morphology to extract the pixels. The matlab code is followed

```
RGBImage = imread('E:\ImageProcessing\Palm\Matlab\IMG_20140817_144549.jpg');
GrayImage = rgb2gray(RGBImage);
GrayImage = imresize(GrayImage, [768, 1024]);
se = strel('disk', 10);
GrayImage = imbothat(GrayImage, se);
figure; imshow(GrayImage);
```

[image]

The curves still have a little higher intensity values than neighboring pixels. Maybe I need use ridge filter to enhance the curves. I use the filter from matlab file exhange(http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24409-hessian-based-frangi-vesselness-filter). The filtered result is not satisfactory. I hope to get any advance or links or papers.

Comment: Pls edit your question with the original question and try to formulate specific questions regarding code/programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a link to another question on a different site.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be difficult from the example image you posted, but here is an approach I would suggest that might get you in the right direction:

Use an HSV filter to segment the skin tones from the rest of the image. Now you just have the palm. Mask the rest of the image.

Next, try using an LBP filter to isolate the features you want. The LBP filter is contrast invariant, so changes in lighting levels etc will be irrelevant.

Or, if you wanted a simpler approach, trying using a canny filter, that should probably give you the lines.

Be warned, it's going to be messy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have no experience with LBP filter. But I will try the filter and report the result later. You said extract of the curves is one difficult task from the example images. Why do you say that? I guest the contrast is low and the feature of the curves is not unique.

Comment: Exactly. There are a lot of features in these images; most simple algorithms will generate a lot of false positives/produce weird results. It's easy for you to look at the image and say 'I want this curve and that curve', but it's much harder for the computer to do it...